# I want to make a tag hanging from the top of the screen that can be pulled and do a special effect

Tags: html, css, tags

Hello I have been trying to make a tag in html that is at the top of the screen and can be pulled by the user to make a special effect happen (eg. Stars falling, random pop-up, ETC.)

I have been learning html for a few months so I dont know much about and could not find anything online.

Note: for the solution you dont need to add any special effects I will try that myself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPVca.png ~ image for a tag

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you please share what you have worked on so far? This will help with getting better answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.